# generator expression/tuple comprehension to for loop for hashes.text.splitlines()

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, generator-expression

[result with the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6LDq.png)I am trying to figure out how I can turn the following tuple comprehension into the for loop instead. In the class video, this was only done in the following manner. I have asked class discord for help and the teaching assistant, but I am not getting any feedbacks that I can understand.
Edit: Yes, I understand that I should not be using the same variable names. I've been commenting out and uncommenting between the original and mine so that I wouldn't have to constantly change few lines below.
------------------this is the original-------------------------------

```
def get_password_leaks_count(hashes, hash_to_check):
    hashes = (line.split(':') for line in hashes.text.splitlines())
    print(hashes)
    for h, count in hashes:
        if h == hash_to_check:
            return count
    return 0
    print(h, count)
```

Below is what I have worked out so far, but not even sure if I am heading the right way; I'm not even sure if hash_to_check = [] is even supposed to be there.

```
def get_password_leaks_count(hashes, hash_to_check):
    hashes = hashes.text.splitlines()
    for line in hashes:
        hashes = line.split(":")
        hashes = hash_to_check
        print(hashes)
        # for h, count in hashes:
        #     if h == hash_to_check:
        #         return count
        # return 0
```

Comment: You have a generator expression in the first line of the original, it probably should be square brackets not parenthesis? Also assigning the results of new expressions to the same variable (hashes) is problematic, just make a new variable name on each line. It would also help if you described the type of object being sent to the function, it seems like hashes begins as a user-provided class instance of some sort, with a string member called 'text'? ?

Comment: I copied the original from what the instructor had in the video. Yes, I know that there shouldn't be any same variables, but I've been just commenting out and uncommenting between the original and mine so I wouldn't have to edit few lines below every single time.

Answer (score 1):

The code is confusing because it reuses the variable `hashes`. Avoiding this, and omitting the first `print` statement which only prints a generator object rather than the values it generates (I doubt whether this is really needed) gives the following. Note that I am also omitting the final `print`, which is never reached because it follows a `return` statement.

```
def get_password_leaks_count(hashes, hash_to_check):
    for line in hashes.text.splitlines():
        for h, count in line.split(':'):
            if h == hash_to_check:
                return count
    return 0
```

By the way, despite the title of the question, you do not have a list comprehension in the original.  Instead, you have a generator expression.  Iterating over it will have a similar effect to iterating over a list produced by a list comprehension, but a generator will have been used in order to avoid creating an unnecessary temporary list in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will change the title of the question accordingly. I guess I should go back and watch a few lectures again.
I just tried your for loop. However, it still does not work.